# Select Correct Word from Autocorrect window open when I select wrong spell word not working in UITextView iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

When I select wrong spell word then autocorrect window open for suggesting correct word, when I select correct word its not update on textview.
[image]

[[image: 2]]

Comment: Please check above Image

Comment: You should show us your code please

Comment: I just write  self.shareContentTextView.autocorrectionType = .yes this line for replacing wrong spell word with suggested correct word.

Comment: How we do that if you know any approch @DJ-Glock

Comment: Can you add screenshot of your settings of the text field from Inspector (in Storyboard)?

Comment: please check this link for image https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pmmi0.png

Comment: Just a guess... Have you used any gesture recognizer in your ViewController class? Can you show code of your view controller class?

Comment: My Problem Solved.

Comment: What was the issue? It will be great if you post the answer to your question. In this case someone else who faces the issue like this, will be able to find your solution.